# Get the value based on object key in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I would like to know how to get the value based on key in nested object using javascript

I have a `obj` which has list of all countries and I have nested object  `list` with country codes

Is it possible to add the country name in the nested array `list` like

````
//Expected Output
var result= [{
"cn": "TH",
"name": {
  "en": "Thailand"
  }
},{
"cn": "IN",
"name": {
  "en": "India"
  }
}]

```

```
var list=[{
"cn": "TH",
},
{
"cn":"IN",
}]

var obj={
 "SG": "Singapore",
 "CN": "China",
 "TH": "Thailand",
 "IN": "India",
 "AU": "Australia"
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
var list=[{
  "cn": "TH",
},
{
  "cn":"IN",
}];

var obj={
  "SG": "Singapore",
  "CN": "China",
  "TH": "Thailand",
  "IN": "India",
  "AU": "Australia"
};

var output = list.map(
                  data => (
                        {...data, name: { en: obj[data.cn]}}
                  )
             )
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with one line of code

```
var result = list.map(l => ({...l, name: { en: obj[l.cn]}}))
```

Working [sample](https://codepen.io/fyodor_e82/pen/RzZdbB?editors=0011)

Comment: A "line" is not very meaningful in JS: a whole library can be written in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation like so:

```js
var list=[{"cn":"TH",},{"cn":"IN",}];
var obj={"SG":"Singapore","CN":"China","TH":"Thailand","IN":"India","AU":"Australia"};

const res = list.map(({ cn }) => ({ cn, name: { en: obj[cn] }}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var list = [{"cn":"TH",},{"cn":"IN",}];
var obj = {"SG":"Singapore","CN":"China","TH":"Thailand","IN":"India","AU":"Australia"};

var res = list.map(function(e) {
  return { cn: e.cn, name: { en: obj[e.cn] }};
});
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = list.map(country => ({
    "cn": country.cn,
    "name": {
        "en": obj[country.cn]
    }
}));
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "cn": "TH",
        "name": {
            "en": "Thailand"
        }
    },
    {
        "cn": "IN",
        "name": {
            "en": "India"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are two ways to add a new property to an object:

**Use dot notation**
If you know the key name of the property, the key3 in this example

```
obj.key3 = "value3";
```

**Use square bracket notation**
This form allow to give the key name dynamically.

```
obj["key3"] = "value3";
```

This form is widely used when the key name is dynamically determined. Like in this example:

```
var getProperty = function (propertyName) {
    return obj[propertyName];
};

getProperty("key1");
getProperty("key2");
getProperty("key3");
```

**in your Case**

```
var list=[{
      "cn": "TH",
      },
      {
      "cn":"IN",
      }]

      list[0].name = "value3";


console.log("******->"+JSON.stringify(list));
```

**output**

```
{"cn":"TH","name":"value3"},{"cn":"IN"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = [{
    "cn": "TH",
  },
  {
    "cn": "IN",
  }
]

var obj = {
  "SG": "Singapore",
  "CN": "China",
  "TH": "Thailand",
  "IN": "India",
  "AU": "Australia"
}

const result = list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push({
    ...curr,
    name: {
      en: obj[curr.cn]
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way to do so is to map through the list and insert the object like this:

`const result = list.map(l => l.name = {en: obj[l.cn]})`